# How to exclude specific meshes for the Distribute Points on Faces node for mesh scattering?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm currently setting up geometry nodes to scatter meshes on a plane using weight maps for the placement. The problem is that there is another, separate geometry node to scatter a different mesh on the same plane. When I plug the geometry input into the distribute points on faces node, it includes the previously scattered meshes and distributes points onto them, when I only want it to be on the plane. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: The easiest way would be to have the plane as one object **A**, then another object **B** that has a geonodes modifier scattering meshes on that plane, and on the same object **B** or another object **C**, the 2nd geonodes modifier that scatters more objects on the plane **A** (rather than instanced meshes in object **B**)